# how open a small page in dialog?

Tags: flutter

I am looking for a solution for display a window over the page like a dialog box but this box will contains a lot of information. It is for my betting game, i display a list of game with a choice between 1 N and 2.

Here is an image of a betting game named netbet :

[image]

As you can see i have selected 2.10 in the game Slavia Mozyr/ FC Minsk and a window appears at the bottom of the page for set the amount of money i need to bet. I think it will be better,because mobile screen are very little, displaying a window over the page like a dialog box. Is there a solution for do that in flutter ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use Bottom sheet which does the exact task. It opens a small 'page' (read: widget) over the normal app screen. It'll allow to place the bet etc. It vanishes when use taps anywhere outside.

Sample implementation is [here](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-beginners-guide-to-using-the-bottom-sheet-b8025573c433). You can also check [solid bottom sheet](https://pub.dev/packages/solid_bottom_sheet).

Comment: Thanks :) It seems solid Bottom sheet would be better for what i want to do no ???

Comment: Yes. It seems to fit your purpose. Good luck.

Comment: do you think it is possible to use ExpansionTile for display a textfield (for amount of bet) and a button for validate the bet ??? So when you click it display all you need using Something like expansiontile ????

Comment: ExpansionTile is mode of a ListView. Instead try using Dialog box. You can either prepare one from the scratch like shown [here](https://medium.com/@excogitatr/custom-dialog-in-flutter-d00e0441f1d5) or use a readymade package like [rflutter_alert](https://pub.dev/packages/rflutter_alert) or [giffy_dialog](https://pub.dev/packages/rflutter_alert)